# Is it possible to make thread join to 'parallel for' region after its job?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, openmp

I have two jobs that need to run simultaneously at first:

1) for loop that can be parallelized

2) function that can be done with one thread

Now, let me describe what I want to do.

If there exist 8 available threads,

job(1) and job(2) have to run **simultaneously at first** with 7 threads and 1 thread, respectively.

After job(2) finishes, the thread that job(2)  was using should be allocated to job(1) which is the parallel for loop.

I'm using [omp_get_thread_num](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH4D_15.1.3/com.ibm.xlf1513.aix.doc/proguide/ompgetnumthreads.html) to count how many threads are active in each region. I would expect the the number of threads in `job(1)` increases by 1 when `job(2)` finishes.

Below describes a solution that might be wrong or ok:

```
  omp_set_nested(1);
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    #pragma omp sections
    {
      #pragma omp section // job(2)
      { // 'printf' is not real job. It is just used for simplicity.
        printf("i'm single: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
      }
      #pragma omp section // job(1)
      {
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 32)
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000000; ++i) {
          // 'printf' is not real job. It is just used for simplicity.
          printf("%d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How can make the work that I want to achieve be done?

Comment: What does `` I want 'this thread (job(2))' to be used in job(1).``  mean? In your code example I don't see any results being used in multiple threads. You are just printing to the screen.

Comment: Do you mean that if you have 8 threads available and 7 threads get allocated to job(1) and 1 gets allocated to job(2). You want 8 threads to be allocated to job(1) when job(2) finishes?

Comment: @bradgonesurfing 'printf' is just used for simplicity. That is not real job. And, the sentence you do not understand is that if the thread used for 'job(2)' finishes its job, I want to this thread to be used in parallel for loop in job(2).

Comment: @bradgonesurfing yes, you are correct. But job(1) must not wait for 'job(2)' to be done.

Comment: Ok then you should update the question to clarify what you mean as it is not completely obvious.

Comment: I've added a link to omp_get_thread_num to show that it can be used to count the number of threads in any section.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing thks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like this?

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel
{
     // note the nowait here so that other threads jump directly to the for loop
    #pragma omp single nowait
    {
       job2();
    }

    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, 32)
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        job1();
    }
}
```

I did not test this but the single will be executed by only one threads while all others will jump directly to the for loop thanks to the nowait. 
Also I think it is easier to read than with sections.

Answer (score 3):

Another way (and potentially the better way) to express this would be to use OpenMP tasks:

```
#pragma omp parallel master
{
    #pragma omp task // job(2)
    { // 'printf' is not real job. It is just used for simplicity.
        printf("i'm single: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
    #pragma omp taskloop // job(1)
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        // 'printf' is not real job. It is just used for simplicity.
        printf("%d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}
```

If you have a compiler that does not understand OpenMP version 5.0, then you have to split the `parallel` and `master`:

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp master
{
    #pragma omp task // job(2)
    { // 'printf' is not real job. It is just used for simplicity.
        printf("i'm single: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
    #pragma omp taskloop ]
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        // 'printf' is not real job. It is just used for simplicity.
        printf("%d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious: any particular reason you suggest `master`? All material I've seen uses `single` - though also without a particular reason. I would assume it shouldn't matter in this case, but one could argue for generally preferring `single` if possible.

Comment: There are three patterns: `master`, `single`, and `sections`.  I'm using `master` as OpenMP 5.0 introduced `parallel master` as a combined construct for this purpose. The `parallel single` version does not (yet) exist. One could also do `parallel sections` and only have one single section, for which the `section` directive can be avoided.

Comment: Note that `omp taskloop` needs openmp 4.5 or higher.

Comment: omp tasks might cause overhead for small jobs, I would avoid it unless jobs are quite time consuming compared to the task overhead

Comment: @amlucas do you have any idea about the task overhead versus dynamic scheduling overhead?

Comment: @Zulan The best way to go would be to measure for sure, but probably the overhead of tasks may be reduced by playing with the `num_task` specifier. I think that a source of overhead is also that the master only is spawning tasks, hence other threads need to wait for tasks to be spawned.

Comment: The overhead question is hard to answer. It depends on the contention and the access latency on the shared loop counter for `schedule(dynamic)` vs. task creation overhead and the amount of work being done in the loop chunk or the task. So, the right answer clearly is "it depends". Usually, the master thread will be fast enough compared to actual task execution, so that it is not the real bottleneck. I have seen cases in the past, where the creator was so fast that it filled all task queues and had to be stopped to free up the queues.

Comment: I guess at the end of the day you can just tune the overhead using `grainsize` as you would with `chunk-size` of `schedule(dynamic)`. I think the tasking approach is cleaner than `single nowait` / `schedule(dynamic)`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from synchronization. At the end of the `section`, omp waits for the termination of all threads and cannot release the thread on job 2 until its completion has been checked.

The solution requires to suppress the synchronization with a `nowait`.
I did not succeed to suppress synchronization with `sections` and nested parallelism. I rarely use nested parallel regions, but I think that, while sections can be nowaited, there is a problem when spawning the new nested parallel region inside a section. There is a *mandatory* synchronization at the end of a parallel section that cannot be suppressed and it probably prevents new threads to join the pool.

What I did is to use a `single` thread, without synchronization. This way, omp start the `single` thread and does not wait for its completion to start the parallel `for`. When the thread finishes its `single` work, it joins the thread pool to finish processing the `for`.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int singlethreadid=-1;
  // omp_set_nested(1);
#pragma omp parallel
  {
#pragma omp single nowait  // job(2)
    { // 'printf' is not real job. It is just used for simplicity.
      printf("i'm single: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
      singlethreadid=omp_get_thread_num();
    }
#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, 32) 
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100000; ++i) {
      // 'printf' is not real job. It is just used for simplicity.
      printf("%d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
      if (omp_get_thread_num() == singlethreadid)
        printf("Hello, I\'m back\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While the solution is fine, the explanation why the suggested `section`-approach does not work is wrong. There is no synchronization at the end of a `section`! The issue is that only one thread even enters a `section` - and the nested `parallel` region has absolutely no relation to the other threads of the outer parallel region.

Comment: I made a typo. I meant sectionS and there is a synch at the end of a sectionS region. A section is single thread, a sync would make no sense.

Comment: Yes, but there is only one `sections` construct in the original example. It's not the synchronization at the end of `sections` preventing the thread to help out in the second sections. It's the fact that only one thread executes each `section`, and how nested parallelism works.