# Is it possible to run omp for without thread 0?

Tags: c, openmp

I have a use case where I want to run two functions in parallel: the first one contains work that I want to execute in thread 0, and the other contains a "for" loop that I want to share among the remaining 3 threads. 
my code is like:

```cpp
void fct1(){
    //do some work1
};

void fct2(){
    int p;
    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
    for (p=start; p < end; p++) {
        //do some work2
    }
};

int main(){
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        if (tid==0)
            fct1();

        if(tid!=0)
            fct2();
    }
return 0;
}
```

the problem is that the "omp for" in fct2 hangs because it also waits for thread 0 to execute its part.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make thread join to 'parallel for' region after its job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573657/is-it-possible-to-make-thread-join-to-parallel-for-region-after-its-job)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a `single` (or `master` if you really want thread 0) pragma. The `nowait` directive will allow other threads to continue running.

You should use a dynamic scheduling in your for loop as it deals better with a variable number of threads. And if  thread 0 has finished its work, it will join the pool.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define end 2000

void fct1(){
  printf("Hey I am thread %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
};

void fct2(){
  int p;
# pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,128) // adapt chunk size to your problem
  for (p=0; p < end; p++) {
    printf("%d (%d)\t",p,omp_get_thread_num());
  } // all, including thread 0, will be synchronized here
};

int main(){
# pragma omp parallel 
  {
#   pragma omp single nowait
    fct1();

    fct2();
  }
  return 0;
}
```